# LibGDX Masking is not behaving correctly in android

Tags: java, libgdx

So I'm trying to apply a circular mask to minimap, it works on the desktop application, but when I run it in Android, it doesn't.

This is the code I currently have:

```
    Gdx.gl20.glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO);
    batch.draw(style.mask, getX(), getY(),width,height);
    batch.flush();
    Gdx.gl20.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
    batch.draw(region,getX(),getY(),width,height);
    batch.flush(); 
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**Desktop:**

[image]

**Android:**

[image]

**Mask:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi below image have different masking effects and how their combination works. This might help you.

Try them once.

[image]